# Extracting Rating and number of review from Google MAPS

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

I am still begginer and trying to extract rating (number of stars 4.1 for exemple) and the number of review for 100 best gardens in Toulouse city. I have made the code below, however, I still cannot extract the needed information.

Can someone help please,

Thanks in advance,
Ilias.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

def wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(element):
    initial_location = element.location
    previous_location = initial_location
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 1:
        current_location = element.location
        if current_location != previous_location:
            previous_location = current_location
            start_time = time.time()
        time.sleep(0.4)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
driver.find_element(By.ID, "L2AGLb").click()

driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps")

# Wait for the page to load and display the search box
time.sleep(3)

# Input the search query for "jardins in toulouse" and press Enter
search_box = driver.find_element(By.ID, "searchboxinput")
search_box.send_keys("jardins in toulouse")
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Wait for the search results to load
time.sleep(5)

# Updated XPath for the rating
rating_xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/div[8]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]"

# Get the elements based on the below XPath locator
results = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='hfpxzc']")

break_condition = False
focus_element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'zero-input')
while not break_condition:
    temp = results[-1]
    actionChains.scroll_to_element(results[-1]).perform()
    actionChains.move_to_element(focus_element).click().perform()
    for i in range(3):
        actionChains.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
        time.sleep(0.5)
    wait_for_element_location_to_be_stable(temp)

    results = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='hfpxzc']")))
    if results[-1] == temp:
        break_condition = True

# Loop through the results and print name and rating
for i, result in enumerate(results[:100], start=1):
    name = result.get_attribute('aria-label')
    rating_element = result.find_element(By.XPATH, rating_xpath)
    rating = rating_element.text if rating_element else "Rating not available"
    print(f"Result {i}: {name} - Rating: {rating}")

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

I know there are very skilled personnes here that ca help ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad that you are using my solution to scroll down Google maps. :)

In current case you are getting rating, using absolute xpath from DOM root, that wouldn't work. That xpath leads from context root only to first rating element.
And `result` variable itself doesn't have element that you defined as rating xpath (it is not context root).

Rating is placed in card container. Card container root is parent for your `a` element. So, you define `..`

Second step in building locator is to find rating element. It has unique class `MW4etd`

So, your rating locator from result element is `..//*[@class='MW4etd']`

To cut off non-rating results, you can get elements list from `result` and check if it is more than 0.

```py
for i, result in enumerate(results[:100], start=1):
    name = result.get_attribute('aria-label')
    ratings = result.find_elements(By.XPATH, "..//*[@class='MW4etd']")
    rating = ratings[0].text if len(ratings) > 0 else "Rating not available"
    print(f"Result {i}: {name} - Rating: {rating}")
```